# How to set snapping specification in web map feature layer (arcgis)?

Tags: arcgis-10.2, arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, snapping

I need to set snapping to snap just to polygon vertex (by default it snaps to polygon vertex and edges).

In this [example](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/widget_measurement.html) and according to [this](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map.html#enablesnapping), the map.enableSnapping() function should return an SnappingManager and then I could set the layerInfo array of this object, setting for each item the snapToEdge property to false. But in my testing the map.enableSnapping() is returning undefined.

ArcGIS javascript API is 3.7 and ArcGIS Server is 10.2.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you import SnappingManager even if you don't use it.

```
require([
  ...
  "esri/SnappingManager"
], function(..., SnappingManager) {
```